# How to evaluate this integral containing a Bessel function: $\int_1^2 x^{-2} J_2(x)\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, bessel-functions

$$\int_1^2 x^{-2} J_2(x)\,dx$$

I can't solve this integration problem. I want to develop the expression using Derivation of the Bessel function and Recurrence relations between the Bessel functions and get the answer.

Comment: Use [integration by parts](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ibp+besselj%282%2Cx%29%2Fx%5E2) to make it into an integral of $\frac{J_v(x)}x$ or expand the Bessel function as a series

Comment: Maple evaluates this integral in terms of Lommel $S_1$ and Struve $H$ functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can evaluate in terms of hypergeometric functions. Recall that

$$J_{\nu}(z)=\frac{(z/2)^\nu}{\Gamma(\nu+1)}~{}_0F_1\left(;\nu+1~;~\frac{-z^2}{4}\right)$$
Therefore
$$x^{-2}J_2(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{(x/2)^2}{\Gamma(2+1)}~{}_0F_1\left(;2+1~;~\frac{-x^2}{4}\right) \\ =\frac{1}{8}~{}_0F_1\left(;3~;~\frac{-x^2}{4}\right)$$

Now, with the substitution $$-x^2/4=z\\  \mathrm dx=-\mathrm iz^{-1/2}~\mathrm dz$$ we get
$$\int x^{-2}J_2(x)\mathrm dx=\frac{-1}{8}\int {}_0F_1\left(;3~;~\frac{-x^2}{4}\right)\mathrm dx \\ =\frac{-\mathrm i}{8}\int z^{1/2-1}~{}_0F_1\left(;3~;~z\right)~\mathrm dz$$
Which from [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQ/21/01/02/01/) we know has the primitive
$$=\frac{-\mathrm i}{8}\frac{z^{1/2}}{1/2}~{}_1F_2\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{3}{2},3\end{matrix}~\bigg |~z\right)$$

Putting back our substitution $z=-x^2/4$ this is
$$=\frac{-\mathrm i}{8}(1/2)^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{-x^2}{4}}~{}_1F_2\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{3}{2},3\end{matrix}~\bigg |~\frac{-x^2}{4}\right) \\ =\frac{x}{8}~{}_1F_2\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{3}{2},3\end{matrix}~\bigg |~\frac{-x^2}{4}\right)$$
I.E, that is
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{x}{8}~{}_1F_2\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{3}{2},3\end{matrix}~\bigg |~\frac{-x^2}{4}\right)\right)=x^{-2}J_2(x)$$

Hence
$$\int_1^2 x^{-2}J_2(x)\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{4}~{}_1F_2\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{3}{2},3\end{matrix}~\bigg |~-1\right)-\frac{1}{8}~{}_1F_2\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{3}{2},3\end{matrix}~\bigg |~\frac{-1}{4}\right)\\ \approx 0.102617$$

Confirmed by Mathematica:

[image]

---

Mathematica says
$${}_1F_2\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{3}{2},3\end{matrix}~\bigg|~z\right)\\=\frac{2~I_0(2\sqrt z)\cdot\big(-1+4z+2\pi z~L_1(2\sqrt z)\big)}{3z}-\frac{2~I_1(2\sqrt z)\cdot\big(-1+2z+2\pi z^{3/2}L_0(2\sqrt z)\big)}{3z^{3/2}}$$

Where
$$I_\nu(z)=\frac{(z/2)^\nu}{\Gamma(\nu+1)}~{}_0F_1\left(;\nu+1~;~\frac{z^2}{4}\right)$$
Is a [Modified Bessel function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.25)
and
$$L_\nu(z)=\frac{z~(z/2)^\nu}{\sqrt{\pi}~\Gamma(\nu+3/2)}~{}_1F_2\left(\begin{matrix}1 \\ \frac{3}{2},\nu+\frac{3}{2}\end{matrix}~\bigg|~\frac{z^2}{4}\right)$$
Is a modified [Struve function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function).

But IMO this doesn't qualify as "simpler".

Comment: Simplify with [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=hypergeometricpfq%28%7B1%2F2%7D%2C%7B3%2F2%2C3%7D%2Ceulergamma%29) formula for $_1\text F_2(1/2;3/2,3;z)$

Comment: @TymaGaidash "Simplify", indeed.....

Comment: You may assume “put in terms of simpler functions” instead of “simplify”

Comment: @TymaGaidash Considering those functions are in some sense defined using a hypergeometric, I wouldn't call them "simpler".